# Jquery Onbeforeonload

Tags: jquery, onbeforeunload, window.onunload

This simple code from jquery is not picking up the unload event. The console says caching is being disabled.

I want users prompted on clicking on each link on my page that leave page, but does not prompt when they close page. Any suggestions.

```
<html>

<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<body>

<a href="https://www.science.gov" id="navigate">science</a>

</body>

<script>

    $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    return('Are you sure you want to leave?')};

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Please note that almost all html tags will not shown untill you put it in a code block. So, people will not be able to read the code. Try using the buttons in the question form wisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an error in your code, you mis a ) at the end

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

change your code to:
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){ return('Are you sure you want to leave?')});

Answer (score 0):

`return` is not a function and it will not prompt. 
Try `return prompt();`

```
<html> 
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <body> 
<a href="https://www.science.gov" id="navigate">science</a>
 </body> 
<script> 
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){ return prompt('Are you sure you want to leave?');});
 </script> </html>
```

Comment: my include of jquery source code is not showing up on code view in html browser. Should that have 'https://'  added to the src statement?

Comment: If it is from same origin(your own server, no need). Otherwise add the full url

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <body> 
<a href="https://www.science.gov" id="navigate">science</a>
 </body> 
<script> 
  $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){ return prompt('Are you sure you want to leave?')});
  </script>
</html>   This is not producing a prompt.